# How to use function in Scala for loop

Tags: scala

I have code like this:

```
case class State(state:Long=0,time:Long=0)

def funtionA(int a):Either[error, State]

var a = 123
val inloop = new Breaks
for (s <- funtionA(a) ) {
      if (s.state == 1) {
        println(s.state )
        println("ok")
        inloop.break()
      }
      else {
        println( s.state )
        println("not ok")

      }
    }
```

How to resolve `functionA` just run one time? I need to run `funtionA(a)` continue to know `s.state` ok.

Comment: Run `functionA()` one time, or until `s.state==1`? Which one do you want? And why would `functionA(a)` return anything different from the first time it is called? Looks like a bad design.

Comment: @Andy `functionA` returns an `Either` and it will execute the body of the loop only once when it is `Right`. It won't run more than once. There is no need for a loop breaker. It is confusing to understand whatever you want to achieve. Please be specific about your goal

Comment: I want to run  `functionA()`  until s.state==1. Because  `functionA`  just let me know what is  `state`  now. My code has other thread run continue.

Comment: @Andy you can try using `funtionA(a).filterOrElse(_.state == 1, error)` that would replace Right with a state of not being `1` with an `Left(error)`.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this loop in a functional language is with a recursive function:

```
 def loop(a: Int): Unit =
  funtionA(a) match {
    case Right(s) =>
      println(s.state)
      if (s.state == 1) {
        println("ok")
      } else {
        println("not ok")

        loop(a)
      }
    case Left(e) =>
      println(s"error $e")
  }


loop(123)
```

However it looks like this is polling another thread which is not a good idea. Look at using something like `Future` or Akka Actors to manage the multi-threading.